# Still getting error This app has 1 unprocessed crash. Upload 1 dSYM file to process them

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I uploaded a new version of IOS on the app store and noticed a message displaying on the Dashboard of Firebase Crashlytics i.e "This app has 1 unprocessed crash. Upload 1 dSYM file to process them".

So, I followed the docs to upload the missing dSYM file from the terminal.
The message was successfully uploaded.
But, it has been more than 15 hours, and still, the error message is there on Crashlytics Dashboard.

Can anyone help me in this ?
Or does it takes some time to udpate on Firebase Crashlytics Dasbboard ?
Thanks

Comment: The docs I followed: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios&authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

Go to organizer -> Archives -> on selected build & version click download debug symbol -> then just get dsyms and upload like the following instructions